# Use a button press to stop file execution

Tags: file, wxpython, execution

I want to have a button that starts execution of a file, and another button that stops execution. The below code does not work, the file continues executing. (The file, in this case, is just a loop that continuously prints out "hello world".) How can I achieve what I want?

```
import wx, sys
from threading import Thread
import time


class mywxframe(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None)
        pnl = wx.Panel(self)
        szr = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        pnl.SetSizer(szr)
        szr2 = self.sizer2(pnl)
        szr.Add(szr2, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 10)
        log = wx.TextCtrl(pnl, -1, style= wx.TE_MULTILINE, size = (300, -1))
        szr.Add(log, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        btn3 = wx.Button(pnl, -1, "Stop")
        btn3.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStop)
        szr.Add(btn3, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        self.CreateStatusBar()

        redir = RedirectText(log)
        sys.stdout=redir

        szr.Fit(self)
        self.Show()

    def sizer2(self, panel):
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.tc2 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, 'Set Range', size = (100, -1))
        btn2 = wx.Button(panel, -1, "OK",)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStart, btn2)
        sizer.Add(self.tc2, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        sizer.Add(btn2, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        return sizer


    def OnStart(self, event):
        our_thread = Thread(target = self.WorkerThread)
        our_thread.start()

    def OnStop(self, event):
        self.dead = True


    def WorkerThread(self):
        self.dead = False
        while (not self.dead):
            execfile("P:\Computing and networking\Python\Learning programs\hello_world.py")
            if self.dead:
                break
        print "aborting"


class RedirectText(object):
    def __init__(self, aWxTextCtrl):
        self.out=aWxTextCtrl

    def write(self, string):
        wx.CallAfter(self.out.WriteText, string)


app = wx.App()
frm = mywxframe()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your GUI is becoming unresponsive. That means that your long running process is blocking the GUI's main loop. To get this to work, you need to sub-class Thread. Here is a version that worked for me:

```
import wx, sys
from threading import Thread
import time

class TestThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.dead = False
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while not self.dead:
            print "hi"
        print "aborted"

class mywxframe(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None)
        pnl = wx.Panel(self)
        szr = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        pnl.SetSizer(szr)
        szr2 = self.sizer2(pnl)
        szr.Add(szr2, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 10)
        log = wx.TextCtrl(pnl, -1, style= wx.TE_MULTILINE, size = (300, -1))
        szr.Add(log, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        btn3 = wx.Button(pnl, -1, "Stop")
        btn3.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStop)
        szr.Add(btn3, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        self.CreateStatusBar()

        redir = RedirectText(log)
        #sys.stdout=redir

        szr.Fit(self)
        self.Show()

    def sizer2(self, panel):
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.tc2 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, 'Set Range', size = (100, -1))
        btn2 = wx.Button(panel, -1, "OK",)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStart, btn2)
        sizer.Add(self.tc2, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        sizer.Add(btn2, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        return sizer


    def OnStart(self, event):
        self.our_thread = TestThread()

    def OnStop(self, event):
        self.our_thread.dead = True


class RedirectText(object):
    def __init__(self, aWxTextCtrl):
        self.out=aWxTextCtrl

    def write(self, string):
        wx.CallAfter(self.out.WriteText, string)

app = wx.App()
frm = mywxframe()
app.MainLoop()
```

You may want to check out the following resources for additional information on wxPython and threads:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/
- http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but the executed file still continues to execute after I press the stop button. Can this code work with the execfile command?

Comment: It should. I just tried replacing my print statement with **execfile("hi.py")** in the thread class's **run** method and it worked for me.

Comment: Does your hi.py loop in any way? I just copy and pasted your code, added my looping file, and had the same result. The file does not stop executing.

Comment: No. Your example didn't say you also had a loop inside the external file you were executing. If you have an infinite loop inside the external script, then this won't work. You don't have any direct control over that external file. You would need to be able to communicate with it somehow, perhaps using RabbitMQ or a socket server or something.

Comment: So what is the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do? i.e. stop a looping script with a button?

Comment: As I said, if the script is in a separate file, you will have to come up with some kind of messaging system where you post a message and the executed script periodically checks for updates. Or you can rewrite the Python script so it can be imported and you can update a flag in it.

Comment: If you want to keep the script in a separate file, put it in a function and call that function in `def run(self)` along with some flag variable to check if it wants to abort.

Comment: How do I update the flag variable, when the imported script does not have access to variables defined in the main GUI script?

Comment: Return the flag from the imported script to the main GUI script. Or use pubsub.